# Can we make extension fields with non-finite numbers? E.g. does something like $\mathbb R (\aleph)$ make sense?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, cardinals

Cardinals have a well-defined arithmetic, but I don't have enough background knowledge to check if this notion makes sense.

Comment: Division by cardinals is not defined, so... no

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to say no. $\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}\RR(\alpha)$ has two possible meanings that I can think of depending on context. If $\alpha$ is an element of an (already existing) extension field $K$ of $\RR$, then $\RR(\alpha)$ is the smallest subfield of $K$ containing both $\RR$ and $\alpha$. If $\alpha$ is an indeterminate, then $\RR(\alpha)$ is the field of rational functions in $\alpha$.

$\aleph$ isn't either of those things, nor can it be. $\aleph^2=\aleph$ according to the usual rules of cardinal arithmetic, which would imply that $\aleph=0$ or $\aleph=1$ if we were to regard this as taking place in a field. So it is essentially impossible.

Comment: how do you know what is or isn't an indeterminate ?

Comment: @mercio As with most things, we use context. Also indeterminate is not a particularly well defined word. It's just shorthand for a nice element of a particular field that we can construct. We can construct a field $\mathbb{R}(x)$ by taking the fraction field of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$, which we construct by taking the monoid algebra $\mathbb{R}^{\oplus\mathbb{N}}$. $x$ is just a name for a special element of $\mathbb{R}[x]$, but its no more or less an indeterminate than $x-1$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can follow the usual ideas, but if it were possible to have an extension field, say $\mathbb{R}(\kappa),$ then all such fields would be isomorphic for all infinite cardinals $\kappa$, since these are all idempotent ($\kappa^n=\kappa$ for all finite $n$). Anyway, although my intuition fears the answer might be not, I still didn't think of a reason that would impede that $\mathbb{R}^2$ with sum $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$ and product $$(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ac,ad+bc+bd)$$
(such would result its product, I believe) be a field. (It's not immediate for me that a multiplicative inverse will nor will not exist).

Comment: How do you handle subtraction if $\kappa+1=\kappa$?

Comment: Wouldn't $\kappa^n = \kappa$ imply that $\kappa^{-1}$ can't exist, as otherwise we have that $\kappa^{n-1} = 1$ for all $n$, and setting $n = 1$ implies that $\kappa = 1$, which seems to be a contradiction.

Comment: True. But thinking again... isn't it more basic? After all... we just don't have a suitable definition for $\pi + \aleph_0$...

Comment: The multiplicative identity for your proposed product is $(1,0)$, and the inverse can be computed to be $(a,b)^{-1} = \left(a^{-1}, -\frac{a^{-1}b}{a+b}\right)$.  There are many more non-invertible elements than just $(0,0)$ (additive identity), namely $(a,-a)$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$, and $(0,a)$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$. So, $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the proposed product can't be a field.

Comment: Idempotents are bad. In a field the only idempotent elements are 0 and 1. Extra idempotents mean you have a product of (nonzero) rings (which can't be a field).

Comment: @Mark those are the calculations I was being too lazy to do myself right now. But for sure it looked like there were gonna be many non-invertible elements.